# Computer connected via SSH to raspberry-pi, can't show Tkinter-window on computer or raspberry-pi

Tags: python, ssh, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspbian

We're trying to connect via putty and SSH to a raspberry-pi.
On the raspberry-pi we have a python program that should show a window with Tkinter.

We want the window to show up on the computer, not the raspberry-pi.

But we can't show any window when we run the program via SSH. It works great and the window is shown (but on the raspberry-pi) if we run the program from the raspberry-pi.

This is our program:

```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.check_var1 = BooleanVar()
        check = Checkbutton(frame, text='red',
                 command=self.update1,
                 variable=self.check_var1, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        check.grid(row=1)


        self.check_var2 = BooleanVar()
        check = Checkbutton(frame, text='green',
                 command=self.update2,
                 variable=self.check_var2, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        check.grid(row=3)



        self.check_var3 = BooleanVar()
        check = Checkbutton(frame, text='blue',
                 command=self.update3,
                 variable=self.check_var3, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        check.grid(row=5)


        self.check_var4 = BooleanVar()
        check = Checkbutton(frame, text='red2',
                 command=self.update4,
                 variable=self.check_var4, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        check.grid(row=7)

    def update1(self):
        GPIO.output(18, self.check_var1.get())

    def update2(self):
        GPIO.output(23, self.check_var2.get())

    def update3(self):
        GPIO.output(24, self.check_var3.get())

    def update4(self):
        GPIO.output(25, self.check_var4.get())

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('On / Off Switch')
app = App(root)
root.geometry("1920x1080+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

When we connect usin SSH, we used to have the error "no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable"
But then we did:
**export DISPLAY=:0.0**

and now we have a new error:

```
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python gui_switch.py
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui_switch.py", line 88, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1813, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

This tutorial (link below), suggests to connect with some -X:
**ssh -X pi@raspberryp**i
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=63637

But we don't know how to connect like that using putty.

Comment: `DISPLAY=:0.0` tells X11 to use a local unix socket. If you configure ssh to forward X11 (ssh -X or in putty, expand the configuration tree under ssh and tick the box for X11/Enable X11 forwarding) then DISPLAY will be set to something appropriate. You need to be running an X server on your workstation though. Xmingw will be sufficient. You should end up with DISPLAY=localhost:10.0 or something similar where port 6010 is actually being tunnelled back to your workstation's X11 server. (The DISPLAY number is the port minus 6000).

Answer (score 3):

For ssh -X to make sense you have to have an X (Xwindows) server running on the system you are ssh'ing from. Mention of PuTTy suggests that system is running Microsoft Windows. All is not lost: there are free X-servers for Windows such as Xming and MobaXterm (the latter free for personal use only).